# Dynamically changing background-url on Dom generating: PHP Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to display an image as a `background-url` in blade with laravel.

Currently I have this: `<div style="background-image: url('{{$rest->image}}')"></div>`.

Where `$rest->image` is a URL pointing towards a picture on my server.
But this is not leading any result; I can't even see the attribute being generated in the DOM.
Can somebody help?

Comment: Try  {{ dd($rest->image) }} in blade and print the result . It depends where you saved the image too. Have you provided the correct url? like if it's in storage location and your saved path is 'users/asd.jpg' then you need to add 'storage/users/asd.jpg'. The storage directory needs to be specified

Comment: The URL is a full URL of a cloud service provider so no problème there. I will check you solution now.

Comment: By curiosity, does it still happen using `{!! $rest->image !!}` ?

Comment: Yes, as for now nothing works.